# new $.fn.MyObject() triggers "Object expected" error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to instantiate a jquery object and I have an error in IE8.
Here is what my jQuery plugin looks like

```
(function($){
    // var ServicesRoles = function(element, options)
    $.fn.Service = function() {

        var obj = this;

        this.list = function(url, params, ajaxParams) {...}

        ...
        }
})(jQuery);
```

And this is how I instantiate my object

```
var service = new $.fn.Service();
```

It works perfectly in FF and Chrome. I haven't tried other versions of IE yet but in IE8, I get this error :

> Object expected

On the line where I instantiate my object.

My version of jquery is 1.8.3

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT : The goal of this class it to make ajax call. It has list, get, etc function which does ajax call with certain parameters.

RESOLVED :
The problem was that my class had a method named "delete" and it appears that IE8 doesn't like it :/

Comment: $ might not exist yet, try console.log it and see if it exist on IE

Comment: if its a independent service, you could make as `$.service =  function() {}` and call its as `$.service` ?

Comment: This works in IE 11, but I cannot for the life of me work out why you want to put a function in `$.fn` and then call `new` on it

Comment: It works on IE9 to (I just tried). I am not very familiar on how class/objects work in javascript/jquery. I just want to be able to create a new class and have the possibility to instantiate it. It there is a better way to do it, I am interested in it :)

Comment: @Tagazok I'm not disagreeing with the idea of creating objects. I'm merely puzzled about why you'd want to do it with `$.fn.Service`. `$.fn` is where you define functions that run on jQuery selections.

Comment: No idea :) Is there a better way to do it? (I just read some tutorials  on internet and as it was working on chrome (the browser I use for daily testing), I didn't try to find another way to do it.

Comment: I found where the problem was coming from (updated my post)

Answer (score 2):

Your `function($)` syntax is incorrect . Assuming it should be a document ready handler, use this:

```
$(function() {
     $.fn.Service = function() {
         // your code...
     }    
});
```

If it is supposed to be a closure, use this:

```
(function ($) {
     $.fn.Service = function() {
         // your code...
     }    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: sorry, I have updated my post. It was what I had in my code already

Comment: If you are already including a closure then you should have no problems. The issue in IE8 must lie within the code block you haven't included in the question.

Comment: I have changed my code just to have a very simple object (see question) and it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

normally the method using extend method is `$(someDom).service`. of you want to trigger this service, you can try `$(this).service();`

Comment: I don't want it to be attached to anything in the dom. I am just trying to create a new object. And this works fine in FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that IE8 doesn't allow attributes to have some reserved words like a function name "delete" in my case...